# Are $B_1(0)$ and $B_1(0) \setminus X$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Work in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'll write $B_r(y)$ for the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $y$, for all vectors $y$ and all real numbers $r \geq 0$.

Now let $x$ denote a fixed but arbitrary non-zero vector of length $1/2.$ Define $X = \mathbb{R}_{\geq 1} x.$ That is: $$X = \{ax \mid a \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}\}$$

Observe that since $X$ is closed, hence $B_1(0) \setminus X$ is open.

Now equip both $B_1(0)$ and $B_1(0) \setminus X$ with the subspace topology.

> **Question.** Are $B_1(0)$ and $B_1(0) \setminus X$ homeomorphic?

Comment: Wouldn't $\phi (x)=\frac{x}{\| x \| ^2}$ be such a homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes. They are even conformally equivalent (Riemann mapping theorem). What sort of theory would you want to throw at the problem?

Comment: Hint: try to draw a picture of your set $X$.  Also there is a very natural homeomorphism (it's even an isometry if you know about those) that you can use to assume without loss that $x=(1,0)$.

Comment: It may help to envision the two "sides" of the cut you made as being "folded together." If you unfold it by opening up the angle at $x$, it might be a little easier to see why this is topologically a disk.

Comment: @XanderFlood, thanks!

Comment: @JustinBenfield The function $\phi(x)$ that you described when applied to an element $B_1(0)$ produce an element outside of $B_1(0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'll just read up on whatever theorems you throw at it; feel free to use whatever tools best trivialize the problem.

Comment: @user27454 That's what a homeomorphism should do, it should map $B_1(0)$ to $B_1(0)\setminus X$ or vice versa (among other things).

Comment: @JustinBenfield Exactly, what I am saying is that the image of the map that you described is not $B_1(0)\setminus X$, because $\phi(x)$ has always norm greater than 1.

Comment: Is $x$ a _fixed_ vector, or is it a placeholder for _any_ vector of length $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @user27454 So I'm off by a scaling factor because the ball is not radius 1? Or is there a more serious problem?

Comment: @JustinBenfield, its a fixed vector.

Comment: I see, then nevermind about $\phi$, I was thinking of this as _any_ $x$.

Comment: Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$. Both are simply connected domains, neither is the entire plane, so by Riemann there's a biholomorphic mapping between the two. That's the magic of (real) dimension $2$. It's also true that the ball and "ball minus closed ray" are homeomorphic in other dimensions, but in dimension $> 2$ you need a different argument.

Comment: @JustinBenfield If $x$ was arbitrary of length $1/2$, then $B_1(0)\setminus X=B_{1/2}(0)$, and still your function does not work and is not off just by scaling a factor. For instance, if $\lim_{n\to \infty }|y_n|\to 0$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty }|\phi(x_n)|\to \infty$

Comment: @user27454 And now you see why I posed it as a question at first (I wasn't sure if that would cause problems or not, not surprised it does).

Comment: Now suppose we replace $R^2$ with $R^3$. What can we say about the Q then ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $B_1(0)$ and $B_1(0)\setminus\left(\left[\frac 1 2, 1\right)\times\left\{0\right\}\right)$ are homemorphic. Since I'm a masochist, here's a homeomorphism: map $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\in B_1(0)$ to
$$
\begin{cases}
\Big(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\Big) \begin{pmatrix}y\\\frac 12\sqrt{1-(2y-1)^2}\end{pmatrix}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}\frac 12+\frac 12 y\\0\end{pmatrix} & \text{if $x\ge 0$, $y\ge 0$}, \\
\Big(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\Big) \begin{pmatrix}-y\\-\frac 12\sqrt{1-(-2y-1)^2}\end{pmatrix}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}\frac 12-\frac 12 y\\0\end{pmatrix} & \text{if $x\ge 0$, $y\le 0$}, \\
\Big(1-\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\Big) \begin{pmatrix}y\\\frac 12\sqrt{1-(2y-1)^2}\end{pmatrix}+\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}2y-1\\\sqrt{1-(2y-1)}\end{pmatrix} & \text{if $x\le 0$, $y\ge 0$}, \\
\Big(1-\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\Big) \begin{pmatrix}-y\\-\frac 12\sqrt{1-(-2y-1)^2}\end{pmatrix}+\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}-2y-1\\-\sqrt{1-(-2y-1)}\end{pmatrix} & \text{if $x\le 0$, $y\le 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: construct the homeomorphism in two steps. Let $Y$ be a narrow cone containing $X$. Show that $B\setminus X\approx B\setminus Y$. Then it is easy to show that $B\setminus Y\approx B$.

Comment: Where is the point of the narrow cone?

Comment: @goblin: So that the obvious function (scaling radially with respect to center) is continuous. Or if you are asking about the tip of the cone, it's the same as the end of $X$.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I meant the tip.